# (How) can I search a graph on arrows.app for a string?

Tags: graph, neo4j, visualization, knowledge-graph

After drawing a knowledge graph with hundreds of nodes and thousands of edges on [arrows.app](https://arrows.app/), I want to search the graph for a node by its name to add an additional node with an edge to that node on the graph manually.

Does the site support such a feature? If so, how can I manage to search? If not, any workarounds?

What I have tried: I switched to Gephi, but I need to download an application and I can only search for the node in the data laboratory and then locate the node in the overview.

Answer (score 0):

100s of nodes and 1000s of edges in arrows.app? I like it a lot, but I don't think it was meant as a tool to do what you are doing, and for that reason does not have those search capabilities.

Whatever you are doing. Did you consider moving to a graph database altogether?

Comment: I don't know if there is an awesome user interface like arrows.app for such a graph database?

Comment: Well, we do our best to build something for non-developers.

Comment: Great! We'll give it a try.